# Can't access Recovery Menu Milestone a853

Tags: rom-flashing, recovery-mode, bootloader

I'm trying to flash a Cyanogenmod 7.1.5 on my Motorola Milstone A853. I can access the Bootloader (version 90.74) and started RSDLite 5.7 and used a base sbf file, which flashes normally.

When I reboot the device I can access recovery mode by pressing <kbd>Camera</kbd>, but when I access the recovery mode by pressing <kbd>Volume UP</kbd> and then press <kbd>Camera</kbd> the recovery menu does not open.

I see videos on YouTube, read a lot of tutotials, but I don't know what to do. Is there another way to do this?

Comment: I'm not entirely clear on what the issue is that you're seeing. Are you saying that you can't navigate the recovery menu? Typically the `Power` button selects things, not the camera one. [These instructions](http://www.addictivetips.com/mobile/how-to-root-motorola-milestone/) also seem to indicate that you should use the keyboard's navigation pad. Or are you having trouble getting into recovery to begin with? You first seem to say that you *can* access it, but then you seem to say that you cannot.

Comment: Sorry I want write recovery mode, but write recovery menu.
I can´t navigate because I can´t see Recovery menu, it does not show, Volume up + Camera doees not do anything on my phone.

Comment: but you said that you can access it by holding camera. What is different about accessing recovery mode from VolUp+Camera and just Camera?

Comment: Pressing Camera button and then press power start recovery mode, with a /!\ on the screen, but there is a step to open the menu, this step is Volume up + Camera, but menu does not show on screen.

Answer (score 0):

Power on the Milestone:

Press the power button and X button and when a triangle appears, press volume up key and camera buttion.